# Put multiple values from elements into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

A common situation is where I'll need to put values from multiple inputs into an array. Is there a one-liner, or simpler method, that can accomplish this?

```
var array = [];
$(".foo").each(function(){
    array.push($(this).val());
});
```

I'm imagining something like this:

```
 var array = $(".foo").getEach('val');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is probably as close as you'll get without creating your own method

```
var array = $.map( $(".foo"), function(el){
    return el.value;
});
```

You could roll your own

```
$.fn.getEach = function(prop) {
    return $.map(this, function(el) {return $(el).attr(prop); })
}
```

to be called as

```
var array = $(".foo").getEach('value');
```

Comment: `var array = $.map( $(".foo"), function(el){ return el.value; });` one-liner! [+1ed]

Comment: Or `var arr = $('foo').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();`